# Caching in a Service oriented architecture

Tags: rest, caching, architecture, memcached, soa

In a distributed systems environment, we have a RESTful service that needs to provide high read throughput at low-latency. Due to limitations in the database technology and given its a read-heavy system, we decided to use MemCached. Now, in a SOA, there are atleast 2 choices for the location of the cache, basically client looks up in Cache before calling server vs client always calls server which looks up in cache. In both cases, caching itself is done in a distributed MemCached server.

Option 1: Client -> RESTful Service -> MemCached -> Database

OR

Option 2: Client -> MemCached -> RESTful Service -> Database

I have an opinion but i'd love to hear arguments for and against either option from SOA experts in the community. Please assume either option is feasible, its a architecture question. Appreciate sharing your experience.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the

> Option 1: Client -> RESTful Service -> Cache  **Server** -> Database

working very well. *Pros* IMHO are that you are able to operate wtih and use this layer in a way allowing you to "free" part of the load on the DB. Assuming that your end-users can have a lot of similar requests and after all the Client can decide what storage to spare for caching. Also how often to clear it.

Comment: Would you reconsider your preferred option after the edit i.e. Its a distributed cache

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Option 1 and I am currently using it. In this way it is easier to control the load on the DB (just as @ekostatinov mentioned). I have lots of data that are required for every user in the system, but the data is never changed (such as some system rules, types of items, etc). It really reduces the DB load. In this way you can also control the behavior of the cache (such as when to clear the items).

Comment: Would you reconsider your preferred option after the edit i.e. Its a distributed cache

Comment: Yes, why not if you mean distributed between server instances.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is the prefered option as it makes memcache an implementation detail of the service. the other option means that if the business changes and things can't be kept in the cache (or other can etc.) the clients would have to change. Option 1 hides all that behind the service interface. 
Additionally option 1 lets you evolve the service as you wish. e.g. maybe later you think you need a new technology, maybe you'd solve the performance problem with the DB etc. Again, option 1 lets you make all these changes without dragging the clients into the mess

Answer (score 1):

Is the REST ful API exposed to external consumers. In that case it is up to the consumer to decide if they want to use a cache and how much stale data can they use.

As for as the REST ful service goes, the service is the container of business logic and it is the authority of data, so it decides how much to cache, cache expiry, when to flush etc. A client consuming the REST service always assumes that the service is providing it with the latest data. And hence option 1 is preferred.

Who is the client in this case?
Is it a wrapper for your REST API. Are you providing both client and the service.

Answer (score 0):

I can share my experience with [Enduro/X middleware](http://www.endurox.org) implementation. For local XATMI service calls any client process connects to shared memory (LMDB) and checks the result there. If there is response saved it returns data directly from shm. If data is not there, client process goes the longest path and performs the IPC. In case of REST access, network clients still performs the HTTP invocation, but HTTP server as XATMI client returns the data from shared mem. From real life, this technique was greatly boosting the web frontend web application which used middleware via REST calls.